# C# Menu System will not work

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to explain this but I'll try my best since I'm new to c# programming.

I have created a Menu System

```
string sChoice;
            //Menu
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Instructions");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - New User");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Record & Score");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Exit System");
            Console.Write("Please enter your choice between 1-4: ");
            sChoice = Console.ReadLine();
```

Pressing 1 will then take you to the instructions section of the console application and so on.

```
//Instructions
            if (sChoice == "1")

            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("*Instructions*");
                Console.WriteLine();
```

I have tried an else statement which will repeat the menu and prompt the user of an invalid key, however this will only repeat itself another 3 times before closing. Is there a way for me to block any other keys other than 1-4 being entered or a solution to my problem

Because as it seems, if any key other than 1-4 is pressed then the console application will simply close.

Comment: Side Note: Take a look at the `switch` statement, it's better suited for your type of program

Comment: Your problem is that your programming knowledge is too limited and you don't know how to face a simple problem. You shouldn't be asking about this issue and seriously thinking that an answer will help you learn (because after this one, will come a new one and then a new one). You should focus now on learning basics and doing lots of tests (by your own, ideally without asking). Once you will get a proper understanding (not even of C#, of basic algorithm building), you might come here and ask actually relevant questions.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton If someone complains about a set of if else statements not delivering what is expected, you shouldn't recommend switch which does exactly the same (although some people might prefer one or the other option).

Comment: Who says I shouldn't? @varocarbas what prohibits me from doing so?

Comment: Aha, I do understand what you're saying however I will learn from it. I just don't have a solution right now after doing my own tests.

Comment: If you can't see why in a menu driven application a `switch` statement is better suited than an `if-else` statement that's on you, and btw that is why I added the *Side Note* @varocarbas

Answer (score 4):

This question remembers me when I was young and started programming.

Maybe you want someting like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int mainMenuOption = OptionMenu("Instructions", "New User", "Record & Score", "Exit System");
                switch (mainMenuOption)
                {
                    case 1: Instructions(); break;
                    case 2: NewUser(); break;
                    case 3: RecordAndScore(); break;
                    case 4: Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.."); return;
                }
            }

        }

        static void Instructions()
        {
            // Handle Instructions here
            Console.WriteLine("Instrucctions done");
        }

        static void NewUser()
        {
            // Handle New User here
            Console.WriteLine("New user done");
        }

        static void RecordAndScore()
        {
            // handle recorde and score here
            Console.WriteLine("Record & score done");
        }


        static int OptionMenu(params string[] optionLabels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Choose an option");
            for (int optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < optionLabels.Length; optionIndex++)
            {
                Console.Write(optionIndex + 1);
                Console.Write(".- ");
                Console.WriteLine(optionLabels[optionIndex]);
            }
            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                int selectedOption;
                if (int.TryParse(input, out selectedOption) && selectedOption > 0 && selectedOption <= optionLabels.Length)
                {
                    return selectedOption;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid option, please try again");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```